# Is there a way to track or get the total number of batch iterations JPA completes before failing due to BatchUpdateException?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have a requirement of persisting N entities, using Spring-JPA (Hibernate) and I have set my spring batch size = M, where M < N.

I will submit all N entities to the repository and it follows below logic

```
entities.forEach(entity->entityManager.persist(entity));
entityManager.flush();
```

The entire operation is wrapped by @Transactional.

Based on https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-find-which-statement-failed-in-a-jdbc-batch-update, It is giving me better results, but the challenge is , BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts() gives the total persisted in each batch operation, but not overall count including all internal iterations before failing.

For eg, if I need to persist 100 entities, with spring batch size = 5

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
```

and 13 record is a bad record causing a failure. BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts() returns 2, that is because it failed in the 3rd iteration of batch cycle. Instead, I would like to get the count like 12 successful inserts. Is there any API or some way of tracking this, without keeping track externally, (this will defeat my purpose, by calling flush multiple times)

```
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);
entities.forEach(entity->{ entityManager.persist(entity); 
                           ai.getAndIncrement();
                           if(ai.get() % batchsize){
                               entityManager.flush();
                           });
entityManager.flush();
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the information about the used database and Hibernate dialect.

Comment: Database used : Oracle 12C  and Hibernate Dialect :  org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

Answer (score 0):

There are several news concerning batch insert to Oracle 12 using Hibernate. Good one first.

**Hibernate Oracle 12 Batch Insert**

Indeed Hibernate (at least in version 5.4.4 which I tested) supports batch insert if you set the property

```
 <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="3"/>
```

It is a bit tricky to recognise it, as the Hibernate logging does not differ from the normal mode logging. Probably due to the fact that Oracle has no syntax to pass a collection of values to the INSERT you see the log of single insert statements

```
 Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
```

But by examining the Oracle 10046 trace you can see that each execution of  the INSERT cursor process the batch_size of rows (see parameter r=3 in EXEC trace line - batch size is set to 3)

```
 PARSING IN CURSOR #347407728 ..
 insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (:1 , :2 )
 END OF STMT 

 EXEC #347407728:....,r=3,...
```

Note that unfortunately you can't use the IDENTITY column for the primary key in batch mode

```
  AUTHOR_ID INT  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
```

using IDENTITY will *turn off the batch mode*.

**getUpdateCount**

The second good news is that if you get an exception in batch processing you can obtain the updateCounts of the current batch - you must unnest the `PersistenceException` which you receive with this pseudocode

```
 e.getCause().getSQLException().getUpdateCounts()
```

Note however that you need to be on Oracle 12 and use the corresponding JDBC driver to see the exact update count - in former versions you'll see only an unspecific error (single negative number).

**Putting it All Together**

So combining those two features you can - at least in theory - identify the failed record

Example for batch_size =3

You see 6 logged rows

```
 Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into AUTHOR (name, AUTHOR_ID) values (?, ?)
```

i.e. there were 2 batches started, the second batch  failed with two rows successfully processed

```
 BatchUpdateException - update count: [1, 1]
```

*This means that 3 + 2 rows were OK and the 6th row failed*

**Summary**

You may argue, that the Hibernate people didn't do their homework and that *reading logs* is not a good approach to identify the problem. I have no argument against this, I can only provide some insight, that you possibly can hear from the Hibernate authors (note that I'm in no relation to Hibernate other than exceptionally troubleshooting the database problems).

**Validating the Input**

This is of course debatable, but while using the batch input you should pre-validate the data so no exception should occur.

**Flush Each Batch**

You arguments against it, but actually there is no real performance penalty in it. On each flush the INSERT cursor is closed and re-opened, but due to Oracle cursor cashing this no big deal.

**Performance Is Not Your First Goal**

And above all, while deciding to use **Hibernate for batch data entry** the performance is definitively not your first goal. You opt for comfortable data entry and you pay some performance tax for it.

My test shows an elapsed time of storing 100K simple objects with batch size of 1000 in about 50 seconds. Which is not a bad average of .4 ms per object, but using a direct **SQL INSERT** to process the 100K rows takes **below 2 seconds**. So for a singular steps, such as migrations and upgrades with extreme narrow time window you could profit from using direct JDBC or event SQL.