# Using Mybatis 3.4.6 for Oracle Batch-Update and Got the "-1" result

Tags: oracle, mybatis

My code like this:

```xml
<update id="biz-update" parameterType="java.util.List">
    <foreach collection="list" index="index" item="item" open="begin" close=";end;" separator=";">
        update
        biz_tbl
        <set>
            freeze_amount = nvl(freeze_amount,0) + #{item.payAmount}
        </set>
        where
        id = #{item.cardId}
    </foreach>
</update>
```

And I always got the -1 result when using Integer or got the false result when using Boolean
And I tried `application.yml` like this:

```
mybatis:
    configuration:
        default-executor-type: simple
```

it seems doens't matter.
So, how can I got the right result of batch-update for oracle?

Comment: You will have to upgrade to Oracle 12 or higher - see similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57586040/4808122)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a batch operation.
It's trying to execute multiple statements with a single `PreparedStatement#execute()` call <strike>and Oracle's JDBC driver does not support it</strike> (correction: the driver supports it).
The correct way is to perform a *real* batch operation.

The mapper statement contains a plain UPDATE statement.

```xml
<update id="biz-update">
  update biz_tbl
  set freeze_amount = nvl(freeze_amount,0) + #{payAmount}
  where id = #{cardId}
</update>
```

The below code executes batch operation.

```java
SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH);
try {
  for (YourItem item : list) {
    sqlSession.update("biz-update", item);
  }
  List<BatchResult> results = sqlSession.flushStatements();
  int totalNumberOfAffectedRows = Arrays.stream(results.get(0).getUpdateCounts()).sum();
  sqlSession.commit();
} finally {
  sqlSession.close();
}
```

- `sqlSession#flushStatements()` returns a list of `BatchResult`. In this case, there is only one statement in the batch, so the list size is 1. If you execute multiple statements (e.g. update table A, then insert into table B), the list may contain multiple `BatchResult`s.
- `BatchResult#getUpdateCounts()` returns an int array. The first element (=int) is the number of rows updated by the first UPDATE, the second element is the number of rows updated by the second UPDATE, and so forth.
- If you are updating many rows, you should flush statements intermittently. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56515063/1261766) for how to control batch size.