# Accessing list element by index in myBatis-mapping

Tags: mybatis

I have the following mapping in myBatis.

```
<update id="updatePersons" parameterType="Map">
    begin
    <foreach item="fname" collection="fnames" index="index" separator=";">
        update person set age = #{ages}[#{index}] where fname = #{fname}
    </foreach>;
    end;
</update>
```

It should update the age of all the persons whose first name matches the one passed as argument.

And the corresponding call in Java:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> fnames = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<>();
map.put("fnames", fnames);
map.put("ages", ages);
session.update("person.updatePersons", map);
```

The size of collections `fnames` and `ages` is the same. I have some difficulty to access elements of `ages` by index in myBatis-mapping. I have tried brackets as can be seen in the first snippet. I also tried `#{ages}.get(#index)` but nothing worked. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#{}` is a placeholder (i.e. `?`) in `PreparedStatement`, so the expression `#{ages}[#index}]` is translated to `?[?]` which is not a valid SQL syntax.
The correct syntax would be...

```xml
<update id="updatePersons">
  begin
  <foreach item="fname" collection="fnames" index="index" separator=";">
    update person set age = #{ages[${index}]} where fname = #{fname}
  </foreach>;
  end;
</update>
```

See the [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for the difference between `#{}` and `${}`.

---

Although this may work given that the driver supports the syntax, it basically is a single big `PreparedStatement` with many placeholders and is not very efficient especially when there are many items in the lists.
If that is the case, you should consider using batch update. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58914577/) for the details.