# Element type "foreach" must be declared - mybatis

Tags: foreach, mybatis, sqlmap

Is using foreach attribute in mybatis/ibatis for oracle sql updates a best practice? Below is my query in the sql map.

```
<update id="updateFG"  parameterClass="java.util.Map">
    
        <foreach collection="entries.entrySet()" item="item" index="index" >
            UPDATE <<tablename>>
            SET description = #{item.value},
                last_mod_date= SYSDATE
            WHERE name = #{item.key}
        </foreach>
        
    </update>
```

When I try to run this piece of code it is throwing me an error:

Error parsing XML.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 49; columnNumber: 72; **Element type "foreach" must be declared.**

Comment: It seems like a wrong DOCTYPE. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html#Exploring_Mapped_SQL_Statements). If that is not the case, check if there is any invisible control characters in the XML.

Comment: Thanks @ave, I could possibly dig more into this based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so when I changed my DCOTYPE from sqlmap to mapper - it worked fine.. I think foreach cannot be used for sqlMap..

EDIT: realized the foreach is not efficient for multiple rows so used batch instead

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the 'best practice' part of your question. The best practice is to perform batch operation instead of `<foreach />`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58914577/1261766). If you use Spring Boot, this [demo](https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-cockroach-demo) shows you how to setup batch and non-batch mappers.

Comment: oh thanks for that.. but in our code we were not explicitly writing any code for committing to DB nor playing around with sqlSession.. Is using foreach considered a bad practice? I have seen people using foreach for batch updates as well..

Comment: If you use Spring, you don't have to manage SqlSession explicitly. See the demo that I linked. Using `<foreach />` generates a single big string with a lot of parameter placeholders which performs poorly if there are many rows/columns to insert/update. Batch executor, OTOH, utilizes JDBC's batch operation API which is designed to process many rows efficiently. BTW, the SQL generated by `<foreach />` is called [multi-row insert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)#Multirow_inserts) to avoid confusion.

Comment: okay great explanation thank you.. we are not using springboot in our app so I think I will have to explicitly open the session in BATCH..
BTW, from your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58914577/1261766) sqlSession.flushStatements() [end of the loop] is committing the changes to database before the .commit() statement for me..? do you know why and how we can avoid this? FYI, I am using/declaring the session as openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, false)

Comment: If you use [mybatis-spring](https://mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html) or [mybatis-spring-boot-starter](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/), you should not call `openSession` directly in your code. Please read the docs...or remove Spring and manage session manually. :D

Comment: yeah we are using mybatis-spring in our application.. why is that we should not be calling openSession directly in our code? is it because the MapperFactoryBean already handling a session and we dont want to have another session?
Also rather than opening session what if I configure this in my mapper config xml file? <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="BATCH"/> - it would still work for single/multiple statements right?

Comment: Regarding how to obtain SqlSession, read this [page](https://mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession.html). You should read other pages, too, though.

Comment: oh yes sorry forgot to update.. I am able to get the session using SqlSessionTemplate.. thank you all your answers.. one last thing: do you know why flushStatements commits the changes to database before the transactionManager commits itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234083/discussion-between-hookup-and-ave).